# Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8 accessing COM Objects Flash ExternalInterface Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, internet-explorer-8, externalinterface

I have no problems running this code in Chrome, it also works in IE8, but in IE8 it gives errors on the website.

```
$("#flash").get(0).disconnect()
```

I also tried this to attempt to fix it

```
var flash = $("#flash").get(0);
if(flash != undefined)
    $("#flash").get(0).disconnect()
```

Both give the same warnings.

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Sat, 8 Mar 2014 22:04:52 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

What should I do?

Comment: try `if ('disconnect' in flash) flash.disconntect()`

Comment: is `in` a valid command?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in